# Expected squared prediction error conditioned on training set

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

I'm reading Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie and Tibshirani, and I am thoroughly confused by the way they conditioned expected squared prediction error in section 2.5 (p.26):
\begin{align*}
EPE(x_0) &= E_{y_0|x_0} E_{\mathcal{T}} (y_0 - \hat{y}_0)^2
\end{align*}

I think $\mathcal{T}$ refers to the training set, and $(x_0, y_0)$ is the testing set. What is the joint distribution that $EPE(x_0)$ is evaluated with?  I can't make sense of what the distribution $f(y_0|x_0)*\pi(\mathcal{T})$ even means.  I've seen many questions asked about their earlier definition of the $EPE$ (p.18):
\begin{align*}
EPE(f) &= E_X E_{Y|X} ([Y - f(X)]^2|X)
\end{align*}
Here, the conditioning makes sense.  I can see that the $EPE$ is with respect to the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ is the input vector and $Y$ is the output vector.  Could someone please explain why the $EPE(x_0)$ written on top makes sense?

Comment: From what I have read $EPE(f)=E_{x_0} EPE(x_0)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation in that discussion is thoroughly confusing. In the derivation of $EPE(x_0)$ it's unclear what $E_{y_0|x_0}E_{\cal T}$ means. I don't see it as representing a calculation like $E(Z)=E_W(E(Z\mid W))$ by first conditioning on $W$, unless there is some inconsistency in notation somewhere.

IMHO a less confusing development would be to write
$$
PE:=(y_0-\hat y_0)^2 = [(y_0-x_0^T\beta) + (x_0^T\beta - \hat y_0)]^2=:(A-B)^2\tag1,
$$
say, and then take expectations conditional on the test point $x_0$ and training data $\cal T$. Under this assumption, the terms $A$ and $B$ are independent (since the first depends on the error $\varepsilon$ on the new observation $y_0$ and the second depends on the errors on the training data) and $A$ has expectation zero (since the error $\varepsilon$ has mean zero). So the cross term $AB$ has expectation zero and the (conditional) EPE is then
$$
E(PE\mid x_0,{\cal T}) = E(A^2\mid x_0,{\cal T}) + E(B^2\mid x_0,{\cal T}).\tag2$$
We note that the first term on the RHS is $\sigma^2$ and the second is $V(\hat y_0\mid x_0,\cal T)$ since $\hat y_0$ is an unbiased estimator of $x_0^T\beta$, so (2) becomes
$$
E(PE\mid x_0,{\cal T})=\sigma^2+x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_0\sigma^2.\tag3
$$
Then take conditional expectation of (3) wrt $x_0$ to get
$$
E(PE\mid x_0)=\sigma^2+x_0^TE_{\cal T}[(X^TX)^{-1}]x_0\sigma^2,
$$
which is the final formula in (2.27).

Comment: This makes a lot more sense.  I'm glad to hear that I'm not the only one who finds the notation confusing.  Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Why does $V(\hat{y_0}|x_0, \mathcal{T}) = x_0^T (X^TX)^{-1} x_0 \sigma^2$ ?

Comment: @IntegrateThis $\hat{y_0}$ is $x_0^T\hat\beta=x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$. Conditional on $x_0$ and $\cal T$, the variance of $\hat{y_0}$ is $x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \operatorname{Var}(Y) (x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^T$ which simplifies to $ x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1}X^T X(X^TX)^{-1} x_0\sigma^2=x_0^T(X^TX)^{-1} x_0\sigma^2$. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306790/145128 which uses $X^*$ in place of $x_0^T$

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @grand_chat that $x_0$ used in $\mathrm{EPE}(x_0)$ is a bit awkward, because $x_0$ is a given test point, not a random variable.

Other than that, the notation in the book still makes sense to me. The main ambiguity of the derivation to me is the definition of $\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}$. In fact, there are two random variables in this notation, (1) the training input $\boldsymbol{X}$, and (2) the noise $\epsilon$ added. These two are independent because you can generate them separately (if the dimension is fixed). So by $\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}$, the authors mean 
$$\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}}[f(\boldsymbol{X},\epsilon)] = \mathrm{E}_{\mathrm{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon}[f(\boldsymbol{X},\epsilon)]].$$

Or more precisely, $\mathrm{E}_{\mathrm{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon}[f(\boldsymbol{X},\epsilon)|\boldsymbol{X}]].$ But at the last line of equation (2.27), $\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}$ essentially means $\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}$ because $\epsilon$ has been averaged.

The following is my derivation of (2.27) ([from my github repo of the exercise](https://github.com/lzhang12/Elements_of_Statistical_Learning/blob/master/chap2/exercise.md)), following similar notation with the authors, but use my own understanding. Hope it will be helpful for someone else.

> Firstly, the training data is generated by a given process, that is, the output $Y$ is related to the input $X$ by $Y=X^\mathrm{T}\beta + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. We use the linear regression model to fit the data.
>   Given a training set $\mathcal{T}$ and a test point $x_0$, we want to know the expected prediction error of our linear model in theory. 
>   This error is essentially the mean squared error conditioned at $x_0$, first averaged over the training set $\mathcal{T}$, then averaged over $y_0$, i.e.,
>
> $$\mathrm{EPE}(x_0) = \mathrm{E}_{y_0|x_0}\left[ \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T} \left[ (y_0 - \hat{y}_0)^2\right]\right].$$
>
> Notice that the expectation of of training set $\mathcal{T}$ includes two random subprocesses (1) generate random training input $\boldsymbol{X}$, (2) generate random noise $\epsilon$. To avoid ambituity, we use $\mathcal{T}_X$ to represent the first one and $\mathcal{T}_\epsilon$ the second one.
>
> The inner expectation w.r.t. the training $\mathcal{T}$ has no influence on $y_0$, i.e., $\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}\left[y_0\right] = y_0$, thus
>
> $$\begin{aligned}\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}\left[(y_0 -\hat{y}_0)^2\right] = y_0^2 -2y_0 \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}\left[\hat{y}_0\right] + \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}\left[\hat{y}_0^2\right] \end{aligned}.$$
>
> Further,
>
> $$\begin{aligned}\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}\left[\hat{y}_0^2\right] & = \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}\left[(\hat{y}_0 - \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}[\hat{y}_0] + \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}^2[\hat{y}_0])\right] \\ \text{(crossed term is 0)} & = \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}[(\hat{y}_0 - \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}[\hat{y}_0])^2] + \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}^2[\hat{y}_0] \\ & = \mathrm{Var}_\mathcal{T} \left[\hat{y}_0 \right] + \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}^2 [\hat{y}_0] \end{aligned}$$
>
> Similarly,
>
> $$\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{y0|x_0}\left[y_0^2\right] = \mathrm{Var}\left[y_0\right] + \mathrm{E}_{y_0|x_0}^2 [y_0].$$
>
> Therefore,
>
> $$\begin{aligned}\mathrm{EPE}(x_0) & = \mathrm{Var}\left[y_0\right] + \mathrm{E}_{y_0|x_0}^2 [y_0] - 2\; \mathrm{E}_{y_0|x_0}[y_0]\; \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}[\hat{y}_0] + \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}^2 [\hat{y}_0] + \mathrm{Var}_\mathcal{T}\left[\hat{y}_0 \right] \\ & =  \mathrm{Var}\left[y_0\right] + (\mathrm{E}_{y_0|x_0}[y_0] - \mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T}[\hat{y}_0])^2 + \mathrm{Var}_\mathcal{T}\left[\hat{y}_0 \right] \\ & = \mathrm{Var}\left[y_0\right] + \mathrm{Bias}^2[\hat{y}_0] + \mathrm{Var}_\mathcal{T}\left[\hat{y}_0 \right] \end{aligned}$$
>
> Since $y_0 = x_0^\mathrm{T} \beta + \epsilon$, $y_0$ is in fact a Gaussian distribution with $\mathcal{N}(x_0^\mathrm{T} \beta, \sigma^2)$, and
>
> $$\mathrm{E}_{y_0|x_0} [y_0]=x_0^\mathrm{T} \beta.$$
>
> $$\mathrm{Var}[y_0]=\sigma^2.$$
>
> With the help of the normal solution, the linear regression model predicts
>
> $$\begin{aligned}\hat{y}_0 & = x_0^\mathrm{T} (\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T} (\boldsymbol{X}\beta + \epsilon) \\ & = x_0^\mathrm{T}\beta + x_0^\mathrm{T} (\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T} \epsilon \\ & = x_0^\mathrm{T}\beta + b^\mathrm{T} \epsilon. \end{aligned}$$
>   where we define a vector $b^T = x_0^\mathrm{T} (\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T}$.
>
> This is actually an affine transformation of the Gaussian distribution $\epsilon$. According to the corollary[^2],
>
> $$\mathrm{E}_\mathcal{T} = \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon}[\hat{y}_0]] = \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X} [x_0^\mathrm{T} \beta]$$
>   where we have used $\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon}[b^\mathrm{T}\epsilon] = 0$, and
>
> $$\begin{aligned} \mathrm{Var}_\mathcal{T} [\hat{y}_0] & = \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon} [(\hat{y}_0 - \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon}[\hat{y}_0]])^2]] \\ & = \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon} [(\hat{y}_0 - \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon}[\hat{y}_0]])^2]] \\ & = \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon}[(b^\mathrm{T}\epsilon)^2]] \\ & = \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X}[b^\mathrm{T}b \, \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_\epsilon} [\epsilon^\mathrm{T}\epsilon]]\\ & = \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X} [x_0^\mathrm{T} (\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{X})^{-1} x_0 ] \sigma^2\end{aligned}$$
>
> Therefore,
>
> $$\mathrm{EPE}(x_0) = \sigma^2 + 0^2 + \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}_X} \left[x_0^\mathrm{T} (\boldsymbol{X}^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{X})^{-1} x_0\right] \sigma^2$$